# Script to change element.style.color in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I am trying to create an effect where an email address dynamically changes using jquery.bubble.text.js

Everything works find except for enabling the text to change color. I'm not sure if it is because I have a span id="bubble" as a child of a div id="colorchange". The script I have used is -

`var x = document.getElementById('bubble').innerHTML;
if(x == "Well, not anything!" || x == "You get the point..") {
    document.getElementById('colorchange').innerHTML.style.color = "#FF0000"
}`

I have the HTML, CSS and JS and a more accurate and illustrative picture of what I am trying to achieve in a codepen [HERE](https://codepen.io/djlowes/pen/OjGrOg)

Thanks or your help!

Comment: That code does not keep running... it runs once and is done. You would need to find some event that the script triggers to say the text has changed.

Comment: I think you should add an `else` to that `if` coloring the text back to white

Comment: `x` is full of `<span>...</span>` it will never contain the text you are testing for...

Comment: `document.getElementById('colorchange').innerHTML.style` should be `document.getElementById('colorchange').style`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `window.setInterval(<function_name>, <interval>)` and put your code into a function, for example:

```
window.setInterval(color_text, 500);

function color_text(){
  var x = document.getElementById('bubble').innerHTML;
  if(x == "Well, not anything!" || x == "You get the point..") {
    document.getElementById('colorchange').innerHTML.style.color = "#FF0000"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if `style` exists on `innerHTML`. If not use `document.getElementById('colorchange').style.color`.

Comment: Well be sure that style doesn't exist on innerHTML, cause it's a string, and that's the only thing wrong with the OP's code.

Comment: This suggestion is really silly. Why would `setInterval` fix something? Talk about a blind workaround! I'm pretty sure the OP's console is still full of JS errors

Comment: You need to run that code constantly. In original question code was run only once

Answer (score 1):

Don't style the `innerHtml`, it's just a string like `"Hello, World!"`, not the element that contains it, to style the element use this :

```js
var x = document.getElementById('bubble').innerHTML;
if(x == "Well, not anything!" || x == "You get the point..") {
      document.getElementById('colorchange').style.color = "#FF0000";
}
```

```html
<span id="colorchange">
    <span id="bubble">Well, not anything!</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Marcin Szwarc

That worked, however the text didn't change back from red to white, so I added

```
else {
document.getElementById('colorchange').style.color = "#FFFFFF" }
```

Thanks for your help!